# ubuntu 20.04 samba fix missing dependencies

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dependencies, samba

I am having samba problems and can't delete samba or fix it here is what I keep getting:  I tried `apt --fix-broken install` but that yields pretty much the same dependency problems

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cifs-utils : Depends: libwbclient0 (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
 libsmbclient : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-samba : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
 samba-common-bin : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
                    Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
                    Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but it is not going to be installed
 samba-dsdb-modules : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 samba-libs : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 samba-vfs-modules : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 smbclient : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
             Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
             Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: The package `2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9` is not in the Ubuntu repositories. That suggests that your package database is out-of-date (run `sudo apt update`) or that you are getting the package from some unusual source (if so, please explain).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. A combination of "improvements" on your command

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install --fix-broken <all listed packages and dependencies in the message you reported>
   ```

   Note that this includes:

   1.1. A prior `update`. You might already have done this, I don't know. But it doesn't hurt.

   1.2. `sudo` in your `install` command. You might already have done this. If not, this alone may be the problem (I wonder about the returned message).

   1.3. `--fix-broken`. This might not be needed, with one or more of the above.
   I would try including this only if 1.2 doesn't work.

   1.4. Manually `install`ing all packages and dependencies. See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/606896/226614) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564282/apt-get-unmet-dependencies-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed#comment1669695_606896).
   I would try this only if 1.2 and 1.3 don't work.
   And combining this and 1.3 only if this doesn't work.
2. Check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for "strange" repos.

Comment: Thnak You that seams to have fixed many things I found multiple references to these in sources.list and removed all but these 2     deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal universe

Comment: Now my problem is unmet dependencies in samba when I try to reinstall it  

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed
Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10 is to be installed

Comment: @TomJerram - Did you try all that was suggested?
Please post updates in the question, not in comments, so everyone knows what is the current target.