# muon is gone after change of python / issues after python 2.7.10 installation on ubuntu 14.4

Tags: apt, software-installation, python-2.7

My muon is gone on my Kubuntu 14.4. If I try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install muon
```

I get the message

```
The following packages have unresolved dependencies:
 muon : Depends on: apt-xapian-index but shall not be installed
E: Problems can not be corrected, you have retained defect packages.
```

(translated into English)

Executing the commands in [Package system is broken. How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it) in all kinds of orders and multiple times (as the answers suggest) did not help.

So what I did then, was to execute

```
sudo apt-get install apt-xapian-index
```

which answered with

```
The following packages have unresolved dependencies:
 apt-xapian-index : Depends on: python-xapian (>= 1.0.2) but shall not be installed.
Depends on: python-apt (>= 0.7.93.2) but shall not be installed.
Depends on: python-debian (>= 0.1.14) but shall not be installed.
Depends on: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but shall not be installed.
E: Problems can not be corrected, you have retained defect packages.
```

(translated into English)

It was then that I remembered, that I tried to install python 2.7.10 on my ubuntu 14.04 (which natively only has python 2.7.6). However, I removed the `PATH` extensions in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, so that

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

is back. I still have python 2.7.10 in `/opt/python` and did not change back the effects of my

```
$ ln -s /opt/python/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2.7.10
```

What am I do do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to explicitly allow apt to downgrade packages:

```
sudo su -
sudo echo 'Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/allow-downgrade
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
mv /etc/apt/preferences.d/allow-downgrade > /etc/apt/preferences.d/allow-downgrade_old
sudo apt-get install muon
exit
```

The answer was given to me at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218955/122989