# I can't install softwares after failed removal of Python 3 (python3-pkg-resources)

Tags: apt, system-installation, package-management, python, synaptic

I have two python in my computer 2.7 and 3.4. I stupidly assumed that 2.7 is the default python in ubuntu and tried to uninstall python3 using this command

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
```

While in the middle of the process I saw it removing firefox and other necessary tools, so I panicked and closed the process in the middle. But after restarting my computer I saw that it broke my ubuntu epecially my desktop. Then I have to painstakingly re installed the ubuntu desktop using these codes

```
#sudo apt-get and sudo dpkg --configure -a these two not working
sudo apt-get -f install  ubuntu-desktop

#after installation
mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old

#reboot
sudo reboot
```

This allowed me to regain my access to the desktop and launcher but when I tried to install other softwares using command line I am getting this error(used both `apt-get install` and `apt-get -f install)` and also unable to install from Ubuntu software center.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 friends-dispatcher : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-aptdaemon : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-chardet : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-plainbox : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

what should I do now? Can I uninstall python 2.7 from my system without harming it? How I install other softwares using command line (eg unity-tweak-tool)?

EDIT

Still after more than 10 hours of searching and teaking the system the problem still exists. Now I have narrowed it to a single problem.

When I tried this

sudo apt-get -f install

the error was pointing to a half installed python3-pkg-resources

```
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 package python3-pkg-resources is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Currently my autoremove dosent work and clean and autoclean return no error. Should I remove python3-pkg-resources? How should I do it and reinstall it?

EDIT2

Searching for solution to fix broken package lead to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/195892/158636) which recommended removing broken packages using synaptic(which i installed before the problem).

The synaptic package manager shows four broken packages

[image]

I then selected a single package `python3-plainbox` and marked as for removal which then again showed other packages depending on this package
[image]

the other three broken packages also show some varied packages depending on them. I tried to re install the broken packages using synaptic manager but its throwing error. Should I remove it

Comment: I don't understand the premise of your question; Python 2 _is_ the default Python. Why do you want to uninstall Python 2.7? Bear in mind it is a dependency for many packages, so if you do want to uninstall it, be prepared to uninstall the packages that depend on it.

Comment: k i didnt know that. I currently have low system space so want to remove some softwares so I have two python of different versions and I thought to remove one

Comment: no, installing python 2.7 will break your system even more. You need both python 2 & python 3 because they are different and both integral to many programs in Ubuntu

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy python3-pkg-resources` say?

Comment: @ByteCommander `python3-pkg-resources:
  Installed: 3.3-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.3-1ubuntu2....
` this is the result

Comment: But then `sudo apt-get install -f` should fix it...

Comment: Nothing its throwing the same error. I cant install any software even tried to reinstall python3 `sudo apt-get install -f python3` getting the same error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 friends-dispatcher : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-aptdaemon : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-chardet : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
 python3-plainbox : Depends: python3-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. 
`

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of searching, tweaking and all other kind of things I have found a solution to this problem

***All the below steps are done without rebooting***

- First I removed all the four broken packages using synaptic programme manager(mark as removal).
- Then I updated my system using these commands

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -f upgrade
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- The above codes I repeated many times (not in the same order) still I got satisfied and will also recommend other packages to install depending on your problem.

Now after a fresh reboot I am able to install softwares and other packages

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```