# difficulty installing vivaldi

Tags: sudo

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I wanted to install vivaldi browser, so I downloaded the .deb package and ran `$ sudo dpkg -i vivaldi.deb`. I received the following error:-
[image]

What should I do?

@karel, I got an error while executing the second line of your instructions:-
[image]

edit:-
I have found out that my package system is broken, I followed this link:-
[Package system is broken. How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f`, then try `sudo dpkg -i vivaldi.deb` again.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Noted.Won't do in the future.

Comment: Why only in the future? You can fix this post as well.

Comment: I have closed terminal.sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libappindicator1 can be installed from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, but maybe something else is preventing it from being installed. Open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory containing vivaldi.deb and type:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f libindicator7 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f libappindicator1  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt clean
sudo dpkg -i vivaldi.deb
```

libappindicator1 is also available from the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.