# "but it is not going to be installed" Nightmare

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a pretty standard "but it is not going to be installed" error on Ubuntu 16.04.01. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So let's go ahead and install that ourselves:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev krb5-multidev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Let's continue:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev krb5-multidev libkrb5-3 libk5crypto3 libgssapi-krb5-2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libk5crypto3 is already the newest version (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2).
libk5crypto3 set to manually installed.
libgssapi-krb5-2 is already the newest version (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2).
libgssapi-krb5-2 set to manually installed.
libkrb5-3 is already the newest version (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2).
libkrb5-3 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and you can continue time and again until you get bored and stop.

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted #Added by software-properties
```

And I have tried to update my `sources.list` with `software-properties` and literally tried everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it) to resolve it to no luck.

Comment: can you post the entire output? is there a misconfiguration error on some package?

Comment: @ravery Updated the question with full output. `sudo apt-get -f install` should have fixed the broken packages, which there already seem to be none.

Comment: do you have `aptitude` installed? it is often better at resolving, and will show the dependency tree, broken packages, holds  etc

Comment: Yes! Finally! It downgraded some packages and resolved the issue, thanks!

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Well, I was going to, but then the question is put on hold.

Comment: The question has now been reopened. It would be great if you could post an answer!

Comment: That's no reason to delete your own question. :-) You can always request for your question to be reopened if you think it was put on hold erroneously which it likely was in this case, e. g. because a reviewer was a bit trigger happy and didn't see you were about to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the issue by installing [aptitude](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html): `sudo aptitude install libpq-dev` which downgraded 3 packages:

- `libk5crypto3`
- `libgssapi-krb5-2`
- `libkrb5-3`

which I was unable to understand that I should have downgraded with `apt-get`.

Comment: ... yeah, and when I try to install aptitude, I get "... but it is not going to be installed" errors there too.

Comment: @SteveB, I get this aswell, in fact I landed here because of that in the first place

Answer (score 6):

I met some other problem like this just saying "depends but it is not going to be installed" and "you held broken package". And i tried the [apt](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/depends-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed-4175608366/) method listed there, `update` or `upgrade` or `--fix-broken`. But what finally happens me out is to use `sudo apt-get install [broken package]`, which of course cannot succeed, but gives you a list of packages which cannot be installed, and i finally found out that some dependency of the packages is already installed on my server, but with a higher version, but the package depends on some lower version of its dependency, so just `sudo apt-get install [conflicted package]=[desired version]` will solve this. If you solve your problem, just a hint next time you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the message given by my terminal initially, but running

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

fixed my problem. I initially ran this command with the package name at the end, but it needs no extra arguments.