# How do I fix this error installing Laravel?

Tags: php, composer

When I run this command `sudo composer global require "laravel/installer"` it produces this output:

```
Changed current directory to /home/zoheir/.composer
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^1.4 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Here's an image showing the error:

[image: screenshot of the error shown in a terminal window with color highlighting]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install php zip extension.

Something like

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

should get you on the right lines

Depending on installed php version you may need to change the package you need to install, eg

- php-zip
- php5.4-zip
- php7.0-zip
- php7.1-zip

Easiest way to find php version is to run

```
php -v
```

Comment: i do it but another errror occured :

Comment: i have these errors 
 php7.1-common
 php7.1-zip
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-zip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Try the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/118755/34472 to fix apt

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Solves the issues.
Replace 7.2 with your desired version.