# Need help with broken dpkg

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was trying to install git-lfs on UBuntu 14.04 . There was some error , some steps which i did at random and dont remember the exact sequence of steps but am stuck at this .

Wherever i try to install any package , i get the below error -

```
root@saurabh-Lenovo-Z50-70:~# apt-get install iperf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iperf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 148 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/54.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 169 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 139 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iperf_2.0.5-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking iperf (2.0.5-3) over (2.0.5-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package git-lfs (--configure):
 package git-lfs is already installed and configured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iperf:
 iperf depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6 is not installed.
 iperf depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1); however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.
 iperf depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1); however:
  Package libstdc++6 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package iperf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 git-lfs
 iperf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@saurabh-Lenovo-Z50-70:~#
```

I tried removing git-lfs by doing apt-get purge git-lfs , apt-get autoclean but nothing seems to help .

Please let me know how can the dpkg be fixed . I dont need git-lfs anymore , so i am ok to remove it completely .

Tried out the suggestions in [Package system is broken. How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it) .

```
root@saurabh-Lenovo-Z50-70:~# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package git-lfs (--configure):
 package git-lfs is already installed and configured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 git-lfs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-get clean and apt-get update work but then the apt-get install -f fails. And i didnt have synaptic installed before this , so now not able to install any new package .

Comment: Looks like your "random steps" broke your system pretty badly. You're probably in for a reinstall.

Comment: Yah .. i am pretty sure libc , libstdc++6 are definitely there , because the system works normally . maybe the package manager list is messed up . No way to rebuild the package manager list from the installed packages ?

Comment: I would try this answer and if it doesn't work, update your question with the errors you get https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it