# Getting Error while removing packeges

Tags: apt, dpkg, php, php7

sudo apt remove php7.4-common

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php7.4 : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: apache2 but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4 : Depends: php7.4-common but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-cli : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.24-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-curl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-dev : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.24-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-gd : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-imagick : Depends: php7.4-common but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-imap : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-intl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-json : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-mbstring : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-mysql : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-opcache : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-readline : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-soap : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-xml : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-xmlrpc : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.4-zip : Depends: php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: **after running the above then the error is** 


`
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php7.4-cli_1%3a7.4.30-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/phar7.4.phar.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/phar7.4.phar'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package system is broken. How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)